# Get trigger inserted row id's in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a stored procedure which updates multiple rows in a column as mentioned below:

```
update tableA 
set isactive = 0 
where email  = ''
```

`TableA` has update trigger to insert into `tableALog` if `isactive` is changed. 
Now in my stored procedure after update statement is executed I need to get `tableALog` primary key values.

I have used following ways bu no luck.

`@@identity` - failed because it returns last updated value. But I need list of primary key values inserted in log table

`OUTPUT` inserted. - cannot use this because it always works on current scope in stored procedure. But I need table values which are inserted from trigger.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: if you need the updated log table primary key in store procedure then you should place ModificationDate and get by this date order by desc

Comment: Cannot reply on modified date because some other procedure might also update same column. This is the reason i need inserted row inside stored procedure itself.

Comment: You might be better off re-working your design (i.e. re-design to eliminate the problem) than trying to do what you describe.

Comment: thank you all. Instead I'm looping through each row using select statement and updating each row. n this case i can fetch @@identity from insert statement which is executed from trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started as a comment but it's getting too long, so...

Sharing data between stored procedures and the triggers they activate is tricky, 
Since triggers can't take parameters not can they return values.
From my experience, The best way to achieve such a thing involve adding a column to the table the trigger is set on to identify the records the trigger is working on, and adding a table (could be a temporary table) for the trigger to output the data and the stored procedure to read from.

Comment: "since the trigger will execute in parallel with the stored procedure, and the stored procedure will not wait until the trigger is done" - eh? In what universe? Each individual statement within a store procedure is executed one at a time, and the execution of each statement isn't finished until all activities (including firing any triggers, updating any indexes, etc) are complete. Where on earth did you pull "triggers and stored procedures will execute in parallel" from?

Comment: E.g. if you execute `create table T(ID int)
go
create trigger TT on T for update
as
 print 'tt1';
 waitfor delay '00:00:05';
 print 'tt2';
go
create procedure P
as
 print 'p1';
 update T set ID=ID+1;
 print 'p2';
go
exec P` you will get the output `p1`, `tt1`, `tt2`, `(0 row(s) affected)` and `p2`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I stand corrected. Memory sometimes serves badly :-)

Comment: @prameela rani, "and adding a table (could be a temporary table) for the trigger to output the data", I have previously seen temporary tables used to pass parameters to a trigger, you do need to add a statement that checks if temporary table exists and if does not exist not to use it.

Comment: thank you all. Instead I'm looping through each row using select statement and updating each row. n this case i can fetch @@identity from insert statement which is executed from trigger.